# WhatsApp won't install via playstore or as an APK... [insufficient space]

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

My partner just received a new android phone.  It looks nice, but Whatsapp won't install.  It gives an "insufficient memory" error.  I've tried to clear the cache, install it from an APK, all with the same result.

The internal memory reports that there is 1.5GB free.

I've already reset this phone several times. It is running android version 4.4.2 and the software is up-to-date according to the manufacturer.

Any other suggestions or tips on how to get it working?

Many applications install without a problem, there just seems to be a problem with YouTube updating and Whatsapp installing.

Comment: it's always helpful to mention the smartphone model and android version

Comment: its a turkish make, model "Dark Evo P55"... can't find much of anything about it online

Comment: Give us the output (screenshots) of [Diskinfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.kuder.diskinfo). You may have to delete an app or an app's data  to get some space for the said app's installation.

Answer (score 0):

Installed a 32GB microsd card into the phone and set it as the default install location for apps.  All programs updated and downloaded successfully.